# Face landmarks labeling tool

Tags: opencv, machine-learning, opencv3.0

I want to create my own face alignment training data set just like MUCT, LFPW or HELEN, etc. Just like the image below.
Do you know if there is a tool for labeling annotations on an image and produce file afterwards?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's not a proper tool for that. You have to define your own UI to collect data from other users.

For example, you can use Javascript and showing a picture in a box, then let the user click N times (N = number of landmarks).

Or for example you can show the picture on Android if you know programming Mobile Apps. You can ask "please, where is the top part of the eyelash?" and so you collect the data and send it to the server.

Sorry about that new, but there's not such a tool to do that ;).

Good luck!